# pushing the same viewcontroller onto stack has odd behaviour going back

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have an AccountViewController embedded in a navigation controller.

This is like a AccountProfile screen with a list of Followers

When I tap on a follower I push the same ViewController on top, and populate the details for that user tapped.

when i hit back in the nav bar, i would expect to return to the previous users profile screen, however it shows the newly tapped users screen after discarding the top.

This is what im doing to push

```
let userId = self.followerUsers[pickedCellIndexPathRow].userId!
let newUserVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AccountVC") as! AccountViewController
newUserVC.userId = userId
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newUserVC, animated: true)
```

this pushes fine, but as mentioned going back discards the screen but the old screen has the new users details in there

how can i fix it - essentially i should be able to stack profiles and go back through them

The AccountViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftEventBus

class AccountViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, SegmentClickedDelegate {

func userClickedSegment(segmentNumber: Int){

    segmentIndex = segmentNumber

}

var segmentIndex = 0
    {
    didSet{
             collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}



@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self


    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true

}

 var model = UserProfileViewModel()

var user: UserResponse?{
    didSet{
        containerCell.user = self.user
        mapUserPhotos()
        mapFollowers()
        mapFollowing()
        if collectionView != nil {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

public var userId : String="" {
    didSet{
        model.getUserInfo(userId: userId)
        SwiftEventBus.onMainThread(self, name:EventBus.GetUserEvent) { result in
            let user = result.object as! UserResponse
            self.user = user
        }

    }
}

var reviews = [UserReviews](){
    didSet{

        if collectionView != nil {
            //collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

var followingUsers = [UserFollowing](){
    didSet{
        if collectionView != nil {
           // collectionView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}

var followerUsers = [UserFollowers](){
    didSet{
        if collectionView != nil {
            //collectionView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}

func mapUserPhotos(){
    if let result = user{
        self.reviews = result .reviews!
    }

}

func mapFollowers(){

    if let result = user{
        self.followerUsers = result .followers!
    }
}

func mapFollowing(){

    if let result = user{
        self.followingUsers = result .following!

    }
}






// number of sections is 2. Section above search and below search
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

//number of items for each section. Section above search will have only one and below search will be dynamic as per images we have
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        switch segmentIndex{//segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0 :
            return self.reviews.count
        case 1:
            return self.followerUsers.count
        case 2:
            return self.followingUsers.count

        default://break
            return self.reviews.count
        }

    }
}

private struct UserPostsBoard{
    static let PhotoCellIdentifier = "UserPhotoCell"
    static let FollowerCellIdentifier = "FollowerCell"
    static let FollowingCellIdentifier = "FollowingCell"

}

var containerCell = AboveSearchCollectionViewCell()
// cell for item at given indexpath: if section is 0 then return cell above search, if section is 1 then return cell below search
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        // above search cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "aboveSearch", for: indexPath)

        containerCell = (cell as? AboveSearchCollectionViewCell)!
        containerCell.user = self.user

        return cell
    } else {


        // below search cell

        print("self.segmentIndex\(self.segmentIndex)")

        //switch item{//self.segmentIndex{//segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        switch self.segmentIndex{//segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0 :
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: UserPostsBoard.PhotoCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
            let item = self.reviews[indexPath.row]

            if let itemCell = cell as? UserPhotoCollectionViewCell{
                itemCell.photo = item
            }
            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: UserPostsBoard.FollowerCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
            let item = self.followerUsers[indexPath.row]

            if let itemCell = cell as? UserFollowersCollectionViewCell{
                itemCell.user = item
            }
            return cell
        case 2:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: UserPostsBoard.FollowingCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
            let item = self.followingUsers[indexPath.row]

            if let itemCell = cell as? UserFollowingCollectionViewCell{
                itemCell.user = item
            }
            return cell

        default://break
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: UserPostsBoard.PhotoCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
            let photoItem = self.self.reviews[indexPath.row]

            if let photoCell = cell as? UserPhotoCollectionViewCell{
                photoCell.photo = photoItem
            }
            return cell
        }








    }
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == self.collectionView {
            //pickedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            //pickedCellIndexPathRow = indexPath.row
            //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showUserRating", sender: self)

        pickedCellIndexPathRow = indexPath.row

        switch segmentIndex{//segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0 : self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showUserRating", sender: self)
            case 1 : //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFollower", sender: self)
                let userId = self.followerUsers[pickedCellIndexPathRow].userId!
                let newUserVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AccountVC") as! AccountViewController
                newUserVC.userId = userId
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newUserVC, animated: true)//push(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                //self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)

            //case 2 : self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFollower", sender: self)
            default:  break

        }
        }

                }
var pickedCellIndexPathRow = 0



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 200)
    }else{

        switch segmentIndex{//segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0 :
            let width = (collectionView.frame.width / 3) - 1
            return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
        default:
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 80)
        }

    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 1.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}




// implementation of function viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind, for section header of collectionView
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    // returning the search bar for header
    let segmentView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "search", for: indexPath) as! TopBarCollectionReusableView
    segmentView.delegate = self
    return segmentView
}

// size for header in section: since we have 2 sections, collectionView will ask size for header for both sections so we make section header of first section with height 0 and width 0 so it remains like invisible.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    // if section is above search bar we need to make its height 0
    if section == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }
    // for section header i.e. actual search bar
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 50)
}
```

}

Comment: you need to post more information or code so that we could help.

Comment: I just built a simple project to try and replicate the problem (a label with some text, and a button that pushes a second view, with a copy-paste of your code), and got nothing. I agree with @BurhanuddinSunelwala: we probably need more code to figure this out.

Comment: @dylanthelion - ok thanks - fyi im using a collectionview that dispays the content on the page the accounVC is added in the edit

Comment: @raklos: There's a lot to unpack here (for starters, I can't find where segmentIndex is assigned a value other than 0). I'll see if I can distill the problem down when I have time; in the meantime, if you don't get an answer, you may want to use breakpoints and prints in those didSets, to figure out where your original VC's userID is being changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am using SwiftEventBus which populates the fields when a network call returns a response.

Stupidly, I forgot to include this in the class - so all instances will get updated without it

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        SwiftEventBus.unregister(self)
    }
```